# Transfer-Encoding: chunked in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, transfer-encoding

I have a server response with Transfer-Encoding: chunked

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Mon, 18 Feb 2013 08:22:49 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding

c7
{<some json data>}
0
```

See that c7 chunk size before json data.

How can I read a raw response stream without chunks in Windows Phone using `HttpWebResponse`?

---

Hint: to make sever disable chunked output, I just have to specify HTTP/1.0 protocol version. But I don't know how to do that as there is no `ProtocolVersion` property in `HttpWebRequest` class in Windows Phone or Silverlight

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm also having trouble with the HTTP protocol for Windows Phone...

Comment: I have added my own answer. Please check it. I use HttpClient now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpClient` is able to parse chunked output automatically 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

`HttpClient` is an overall cool thing with PostAsync and GetAsinc and tons of other goodness.
I never-ever use HttpWebRequest again.

`HttpClient` is readily available in .NET Framework 4.5, Windows 8, or Windows Phone 8.1

Use NuGet package http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http if you need HttpClient in
- .NET Framework 4
- Windows Phone Silverlight 7.5
- Silverlight 4
- Portable Class Libraries

Answer (score 0):

You can read chunked response in the following way:

```
public static byte[] ReadChunkedResponse(this WebResponse response)
    {
        byte[] buffer;

        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                var content = new StringBuilder();
                while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    content.Append((char)streamReader.Read());
                }

                buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content.ToString());
            }
        }

        return buffer;
    }
```